# ASP.NET MVC 4 Razor - Trying to find the username of a user

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

All Code

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
<div class="Comment-Box">
    <p>@item.UserId</p>
    @(Membership.GetUser(item.UserId.ToString()).UserName)
      @if (Membership.GetUser() != null)
        {
           if(User.IsInRole("Admin") || item.UserId == (int)Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey){
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "DeleteComment", new { id=item.Id })
           }
        }
</div>
}
```

Problem Code

```
 @(Membership.GetUser(item.UserId.ToString()).UserName)
```

The problem is when I access this page the method returns null and doesn't find the user name, I'm new to ASP.Net and MVC 4 and was just wondering why it doesn't work? and how to get around it.
Any response would be appreciated.

Comment: What's funny is that in Resharper it highlights "Membership.GetUser(item.UserId.ToString())" as a possible null reference exception immediately.  I'm looking into it.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using SimpleMembership, you may not be able to use that method in Membership.  SimpleMembership does not give you everything (it's simple), just enough for authentication and authorization.

As an alternative, you could add the usernames to your Model and pass it in from the controller.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the response, but I figured out a simple solution to my problem. Learning of a UserContext that I can user to get usernames in the Models folder.

Solution Code

```
<p>
    @{
        Amity.Web.Models.UsersContext db = new Amity.Web.Models.UsersContext();   
    }
</p>
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
 <div class="Comment-Box">
    <p>@item.UserId</p>
    @db.UserProfiles.FirstOrDefault(user => user.UserId == item.UserId).UserName
    @if (Membership.GetUser() != null)
        {
          if(User.IsInRole("Admin") || item.UserId == (int)Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey){
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "DeleteComment", new { id=item.Id })
           }
        }
</div>
}
```

Getting user context

```
Amity.Web.Models.UsersContext db = new Amity.Web.Models.UsersContext();
```

Getting the user name

```
@db.UserProfiles.FirstOrDefault(user => user.UserId == item.UserId).UserName
```